# Material Design: Material joining

Tags: css, animation, material-design

Material design has the concept of [Material Joining](https://material.io/guidelines/motion/transforming-material.html#transforming-material-joining-dividing). The idea is that "Material may join with other material, or it may divide into multiple pieces. As two pieces of material approach one another, their edges meet and margins overlap before the movement completes." There is a really good visual at the [Material Design spec](https://material.io/guidelines/motion/transforming-material.html#transforming-material-joining-dividing).

This concept seems incredibly difficult to implement on the web. I have tried various strategies and they all resulted in failure. [Here](https://codepen.io/taylor1791/pen/qXLNBz) is one of my attempts. My attempt violates gotcha 2 because the shadow appears above the siblings until the transition is complete. It also violates gotcha 3 because the transitions timings are not "inverses" of each other and more importantly the shadow appears in-between material sheets along the edges before the sheets join.

Here are some of the gotchas I found:

1) It must work with most box shadows. Box shadows visualize the height of material in material design. The higher the material the larger the shadows.

2) Box shadow can *never* appear above sibling elements - even during transitions.

3) Box shadows must be a consistent darkness before, during, and after the transition.

It is really easy to get an almost spec compliant implementation and most people will not notice the difference between a spec compliant one or not. I suspect a great deal of time and thought was put into the material design spec and to ignore the details would be disrespectful of their efforts.

One of my attempts:

```
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    background: #f39c12;
  }
  .parent, .material.appart {
    transition: all 0.4s, box-shadow .1s .3s;
  }
  .parent.active, .material.appart {
    transition: all 0.4s, box-shadow .3s .1s;
  }
  .parent, .material {
    transition: all 0.4s, box-shadow .3s .15s;
  }
  .parent {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    border-radius: 2px;
  }
  .parent.appart { 
    box-shadow: none;
  }

  .material {
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 2px;
  }

  .material:last-child {
    box-shadow: 0 1p 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), 0 1p 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  }

  .material.appart {
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,1);
  }
</style>
<div class="parent">
 <div class="material"></div>
  <div class="material"></div>
  <div class="material"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.material').click(function() {
     $('.material').toggleClass('appart');
     $('.parent').toggleClass('appart');
  });
</script>
```